# How to I find specific generic overload using reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-3.5, linq-expressions

I am attempting to create an `Expression` that will invoke a specific generic overloaded method (`Enumerable.Average` in my first test case). The specific type bindings are not known until runtime however so I need to use `Reflection` to find and create the correct generic method (the `Expression` is being created from parsed text).

So if I know at runtime that I want to find this specific overload:

```
public static double Average<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector)
```

How do I resolve that particular `MethodInfo` using reflection?

So far I have the following selection statement:

```
MethodInfo GetMethod(Type argType, Type returnType)
{
    var methods = from method in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
      where method.Name == "Average" &&
      method.ContainsGenericParameters &&                              
      method.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
      // and some condition where method.GetParameters()[1] is a Func that returns type argType
      method.ReturnType == returnType
      select method;

      Debug.Assert(methods.Count() == 1);
      return methods.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The above narrows it down to three overloads but I want to reflect and find the specific overload that takes a `Func<TSource, int>` where `argType == typeof(int)`.

I am stumped and any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a relevant answer by Sam Saffron here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection/. The question is about extension methods, but the answer is still relevant to your question, as the extension method in question (System.Enumerable.Where) is an overloaded generic method much like yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>You need to use [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx)</strike>

EDIT: OK, I had misunderstood the problem... This method should do what you want :

```
MethodInfo GetMethod(Type argType, Type returnType)
{
    var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { argType });
    Console.WriteLine(enumerableType);
    var methods = from method in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
      let parameters = method.GetParameters()
      let genParams = method.GetGenericArguments()
      where method.Name == "Average" &&
      method.ContainsGenericParameters &&                              
      parameters.Length == 2 &&
      parameters[1].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>) &&
      parameters[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[1] == argType &&
      method.ReturnType == returnType
      select method;

      return methods.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Correct, but first I need to find the right MethodInfo to create the implementation from. Enumerable.Average has overload that takes Func<T, int>, Func<T, double>, Func<T, Decimal> etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're building an expression rather than executing directly, you can skip the MethodInfo step and go straight to the MethodCallExpression using the Expression.Call overload that takes a method name rather than a MethodInfo.

```
var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
             "Average",
            new Type[] { typeof(MyTSource) },
            enumerableParameter, lambdaParameter
                );
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I missed that overload to Call. I'll have to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

```
static MethodInfo GetMethod(Type argType, Type returnType)
{
    var methods = from m in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                  where m.ContainsGenericParameters
                  && m.Name == "Average"
                  && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>)
                  && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[1] == returnType
                  select m;
    return methods.First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Joren for the linked hint. That example differentiates based on argument count to but it got me in the right direction.

The selection that works is

```
var methods = from method in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
where method.Name == Name &&
method.ContainsGenericParameters &&                                                    
method.ReturnType == returnType &&
method.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
method.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2 &&
method.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[1] == argType
select method;
```