# GetMethod with generic overload

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, generic-programming

I have a class with two methods, overloaded with identical name and arguments, but one is generic:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar(string s) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public T Bar<T>(string s) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

How can I get the `MethodInfo` for one of these methods?

E.g:

```
var fooType = typeof(Foo);
var methodInfo = fooType.GetMethod("Bar", new[] { typeof(string) }); // <-- [System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.]
```

[.NET Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xnMZRv)

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465715/how-to-i-find-specific-generic-overload-using-reflection

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ to get generic or non generic one:

```
fooType.GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Bar" && m.IsGenericMethod)
```

To get the non generic overload just negate the result of `m.IsGenericMethod`.

Comment: That'll work.  I guess I just have to manually match the types in it.