# How can I use Where<T> extension method when T is unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, generic-collections

I’m programming C# MVC application using JSON and try to retrieve the JSON back to the DB using EF.

Unfortunatly, I connot make such code working:

```
IEnumerable<object> NewValueSubCollection = (IEnumerable<object>)NewValue.GetType().GetProperty(col.Name).GetValue(NewValue, null);
//Where col is a property of an object of type (IEnumerable<???>)

foreach (var line in ((IEnumerable<object>)col.GetValue(originalEntity, null)).ToList<object>())
{
    Type lineType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(line.GetType());
    var lineEntitySet = context.GetEntitySet(lineType);
    EntityKey lineKey = context.CreateEntityKey(lineEntitySet.Name, line);
    if (NewValueSubCollection.Where(lineKey).Count() == 0) //See bellow
    context.DeleteObject(line);
}
```

Where I’ve implemented this:

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    //Enable searching in a collection is an entity Key exist... and retrieve info.
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,EntityKey key)
    {
        return Enumerable.Where(source, CreateFilterExpressionBasedOnKey<T>(key).Compile());
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> CreateFilterExpressionBasedOnKey<TInput>(Type sourceType, EntityKey key)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "");

        Expression myFilter = Expression.Constant(true);
        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in key.EntityKeyValues)
            {
                Expression Left = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, item.Key.ToString());
                Expression Right = Expression.Constant(item.Value);

                myFilter = Expression.AndAlso(myFilter, Expression.Equal(Left, Right));
            }
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, bool>>(myFilter, param);
    }
}
```

The problem is that NewValueSubCollection is of type: `IEnumerable<object>` when I wish I could pass `IEnumerable<MyListObjectType>` through my Where extension….
Then I’ve got an exception at runtime:
System.ArgumentException: 'TOId' is not a member of type 'System.Object'

If I Use:

```
Type generic = typeof(Collection<>);
Type typeArgs = (NewValue.GetType().GetProperty(col.Name).GetValue(NewValue, null)).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type constructed = generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
o = NewValue.GetType().GetProperty(col.Name).GetValue(NewValue, null);
```

I get a compilation error with following code:

```
if (o.Where(lineKey).Count() == 0) //error!!!
// 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Where' acception a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: What are the exceptions / compiler errors you get?

Comment: when working with IEnumerable<object> I've got:

Comment: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: 'TOId' is not a member of type 'System.Object'
when trying to execute the Left Expression
and when I use o.Where:
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Where' acception a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing directive or an assembly reference?)
but this error message is 'normal'

Comment: in that case TOId is part of the key of the object...

Comment: The Where Extensions method in on collections and you are trying to call it an object type if (o.Where(lineKey).Count() == 0) //error!!!

Comment: I know but how can I make this work then??? i cannot declare o with var.... otherwise my o.Where doesn't work neither... and eventhough I know it's an IEnumerable<T> I don't know the type of T on advance...

Comment: What version of the framework are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to access this dynamically, but you can avoid some of the headache of reflection using the 'dynamic' keyword.

So this:

```
NewValueSubCollection.Where(lineKey).Count() == 0
```

Becomes this:

```
NewValueSubCollection.Cast<dynamic>().Where(d => lineKey(d)).Count() == 0
```

Or (simpler and more efficient, if enumeration has no side effects) this:

```
!NewValueSubCollection.Cast<dynamic>().Any(d => lineKey(d))
```

---

A simple proof of concept program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        IEnumerable<object> objects = list;
        Func<string, bool> func = s => s.Contains("x");

        list.Add("Test");
        list.Add("x");
        list.Add("mux");
        foreach (var item in objects.Cast<dynamic>().Where(d => func(d)))
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, with this Issue, the Type is now a HashSet and even if I redefine the where extension methode to take/retrieve HashSet; at runtime, I get the following error: `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<LW.Domain.Entities.OrderLine>' does not contain a definition for 'Where'`

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you `NewValueSubCollection` is statically type as `IEnumerable<object>`, so your parametrized type `T` is `object`, and when you compile your expression it tries to find the property on the object class, thus the exception.

In the same way your `o.Where(...)` cannot work because the `Where` extension method is defined on `IEnumerable<>`, and the methods are resolved statically at compile time.

I'm afraid you'll have to invoke the `Where` method by reflection, you might find some help here: [How do I invoke an extension method using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I was afraid of... My Prime interest to go for extension method was to have a clean code... If I have to call it dynamicly; then advantages to use it (in that context of course) are near to nill...