# Calling non-static generic method with dynamic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, json.net

I'm trying to call a generic method with a type detemirned at runtime. This call: `Type type = ...; jToken.Value.Value<type>();` on a [JToken](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) object.

I've come this far, and I believe I'm almost there. But I'm getting a "parameter count mismatch" exception when calling `Invoke`. I can't figure out why.

```
public void Foo(JObject obj, Type type)
{
    foreach (var valuePair in obj)
    {
        JToken jToken = valuePair.Value;
        var genericMethod = jToken.GetType().GetMethod("Value").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {type});
        // should call jToken.Value<type>()
        var value = genericMethod.Invoke(jToken, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value()` method of `JObject` require a Key Parameter, but you are not specifying that parameter, so can't find a method with 0 parameters and throw the exception.

Comment: Okay here's a strange one. If I put a breakpoint after the `jToken` declaration and in the immediate window type: `jToken.Value<int>()` then I get the expected result. If I however put `jToken.Value<int>("someKey")` then it fails with "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue"

Comment: @Snæbjørn There's a reason for that. The JToken class has a method named "Value" with one parameter, the key. But, there are extension methods for the instances of JToken, one of them is Value<T>(), that's the method you are calling in the inmediate window, not the Value method of the JToken class. That method not even exists in JToken, it not belongs there, it's a static method. For the compiler using this method is the same as write `StaticExtensionClass.Value<T>(jToken)`

Comment: @Snæbjørn A `JValue` doesn't have a child.  It represents a primitive value such as a string, number, bool or null.  You can check its type by looking at the `Type` property.

Comment: @frikinside I see, perhaps I should refactor into using the static method as it seems cleaner :)

Comment: Haha okay extension methods are not "cleaner" to call via reflection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection

Comment: @Snæbjørn I'm glad to see that you figured out! The generic type always ofuscate the Invoke Member strategy, sometimes it cleanner (but not always better) to look for a workaround to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

`JToken.Value` needs a parameter: the key of the value. So you would do:

```
var value = genericMethod.Invoke(jToken, new[] { valuePair.Key });
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. However it needs to be `Invoke(obj, new[] { valuePair.Key });` else it'll throw "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue". There seems to be a method that takes 0 parameters if you call fx `jToken.Value<int>()` it doesn't require a parameter, but the reflection engine doesn't seem to find it. So instead I need to call `obj.Value<int>("keyname")`