# Dynamic Linq on method called with generic type via reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a Query Extender, which has a CustomExpression that I want to use to do some filtering on my datasource.

This is in a DynamicData website so I don't know the object type(current entity) at compile time. Say I knew the object type at compile time, then I could do something like this:

```
protected void GameFiltering(object sender, CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
{
        e.Query = e.Query.Cast<Resource>().Where(x => x.GameId == GameId);
}
```

I can get the type I need from `e.Query.ElementType`. Now I just to send the ElementType as a generic parameter to the Cast method and then call the linq method Where.

I'm gonna assume that every Type is going to have a GameId property which I'll want to filter by.

```
MethodInfo method = e.Query.GetType().GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { e.Query.ElementType });
var castedQuery = method.Invoke(e.Query, null);
```

This is how I call the cast method with reflection, but I don't know how I can call the linq method on the resulting object.

Comment: have you tried using [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/Dd264741.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I invoke an extension method using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection)

Comment: The answer in the link above contains a description on how to call the correct `Where` overload via Reflection. Basically, you have to loop through all the existing `Where` methods defined on `System.Linq.Enumerable` and search for the fitting one. Then build a `Func<Resource, bool>` to pass as parameter.

Comment: If all your types have a property `GameID` why not implementing a common interface and cast to that. Then you can call `Where` on that instance.

Comment: because they are generated automatically from the database via Entity Framework.

Comment: Sure, but you can however cast to that interface instead of the actual type. Hust use `Enumerable.Cast` for the interface instead od the database-type and you get what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume all items have the property, you don't need to cast them.

```
protected void GameFiltering(object sender, CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Query = e.Query.Where(obj => (int)obj.GetType().GetProperty("GameId").GetValue(obj, null) == GameId)
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I tried this: e.Query = e.Query.Cast<Object>().Where(x => (short)x.GetType().GetProperty("GameId").GetValue(x, null) == GameId); Still have to cast to something otherwise I can't call Where on e.Query. This works but when I try to do the DataBind() on my gridview I get an error saying it was expecting an QueryObject of type Resource but it got a QueryObject of type Object

Comment: What type is `e.Query`?

Comment: {System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<OfferManagementBackOffice.Resource>}