# Casting object to generic type in order to use IEnumerable.Where

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I'm trying to implement some filtering in my Dynamic Data + EF website and I'm using a `QueryExtender` with a `CustomExpression`. In the `OnQuerying` event of the `CustomExpression` I have access to `e.Query`(where e is of type `CustomExpressionEventArgs`) which is the Query that is used to get the data from the database. In order to filter the data I need to make changes to this query.

Now this query is of type `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>`, where T is only known at runtime. I'm going to assume that whatever type T is, it's going to have a property called `GameId`. What I need to do is do a simple `Where` LINQ statement on this collection where I filter by that property.

```
short GameId = Convert.ToInt16(Session["GlobalGameFilter"]);
Type currentType = e.Query.ElementType;
//ObjectQuery implements IQueryable and I want to cast to ObjectQuery<CurrentType> 
MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { currentType });
var castedQuery = method.Invoke(e.Query, new object[]{e.Query});
```

This works, now `castedQuery` is of type `ObjectQuery<currentType>`

The problem is that in order to use `castedQuery.Where()` I need to cast it to an `IEnumerable<currentType>`, I can't just cast it to the non-generic `IEnumerable`.

I tried calling Where via reflection (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection)):

```
var whereMethods = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
.Where(mi => mi.Name == "Where");
MethodInfo whereMethod = null;
foreach (var methodInfo in whereMethods)
{
    var paramType = methodInfo.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType;
    if (paramType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2)
    {
        whereMethod = methodInfo;
    }
}

whereMethod = whereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(currentType);

var ret = whereMethod.Invoke(castedQuery, new object[] { castedQuery, BuildEqFuncFor<Placement>("GameId", GameId) });
```

But ret is always an empty collection.

Edit: You can see that I hardcoded the type in that last line to be placement (just for testing), but I'd need that to be currentType of course.

Edit2: If I try this

```
foreach(var item in castedQuery as IEnumerable)
{
    var itemGameId = item.GetType().InvokeMember("GameId", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null);
}
```

it works, itemGameId actually gets the gameId that i need so the problem must be that the predicate is not being used correctly.

Edit 3: Tried implementing a common interface

```
public interface IGameId
{
    short GameIdGetter { get; }
}
public partial class Placement : IGameId
{
    public short GameIdGetter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GameId;
        }
    }
}

e.Query = e.Query.Cast<IGameId>().Where(x => x.GameIdGetter == GameId);
```

Get an error here when I try to enumerate e.Query : `{"Unable to cast the type 'OfferManagementBackOffice.Placement' to type 'OfferManagementBackOffice.IGameId'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."}`

Comment: It's hard to know which exact step is causing a problem - for example, whether it's all working fine, and it's just that your where predicate never matches. It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: you are  looping did you try to break the loop when condition already satisfied? it seems that `whereMethod` is always overwritten

Comment: Would it help to have an `IGameID` interface?

Comment: there's more than one where method, I just need to get the right one. That part is fine.

Comment: try to breakpoint your code.

Comment: I agrred with @Ross Presser as you said "I'm going to assume that whatever type T is, it's going to have a property called GameId. " so better make a base class and then voila

Comment: I'd prefer an interface, not a base class, but YMMV.

Comment: How would that help me? The problem is that I can't get the where to work correctly.  Also, I cannot debug the Func that is used as a predicate cause it uses a lambda expression. I'm pretty sure the problem is the predicate, because when debugging I can see that the castedQuery contains all of the query elements casted to the correct type so it's probably never matching the predicate for some reason

Comment: Because you make your query `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<IInterfaceThatDefinesGameId>` and it's much easier from there.

Comment: The problem is that my classes are generated automatically by EF, so I can't really change them to implement that interface because if I ever change my model they will get overwritten

Comment: Does/can EF's generation use `partial class`? (I don't know without checking), if it did you could have separate `partial class` declarations saying they implement the interface.

Comment: It does, and I tried it (edited the original post) but still doesn't work.