# MethodInfo's GetMethod for Dictionary objects's "Any" method

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection, typeof, methodinfo

I am using below method to create the expression for searching a string in an entity

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
```

this works fine in the case of string. But when I tried with the Dictionary object as

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).GetMethod("Any", new[] { typeof(Func<string,string>),typeof(bool)});
```

but it returns null value always. Anybody let me know how to use the method to get correct value of the MethodInfo

Answer (score 2):

`Any` is not a method of `Dictionary<K, V>`. It is an extension method belonging to [`Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx). Therefore you can't find it on `Dictionary<K, V>`.

See [How do I invoke an extension method using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection) how it should be done.

Comment: Can we use "Contains" instead? If yes how?

Comment: If you just want to match on the key, you should use `Contains`.