# Expression.Call No method 'Select' exists on type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am building expressions for entity framework at run time and I have solved all problems except selecting a property from a child ICollection.

It is difficult to post my whole framework but here is what I have tried.

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "w");
Expression.Property(entity, propertyName);
```

> w.Roles

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TChild), "z");
Expression.Property(entity, propertyName);
```

> z.ApplicationRole.Name

This line throws the error.

```
Expression.Call(property, "Select", null,(MemberExpression)innerProperty);
```

This is the error.

> No method 'Select' exists on type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[ApplicationUserRole]

This is what I am trying to produce dynamically.

```
await context.Users.Where(c => c.Roles
                                .Select(x => x.ApplicationRole.Name)
                                .Contains("admin"))
                   .ToListAsync();
```

I'd appreciate anyone who could help.

Comment: Select is an extension method in System.Linq namespace, so you cannot call it directly on the object with reflection.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in comment, `Select` is not a method of IColletion, it's an extension method and you couldn't invoke `Select` directly from `ICollection`.

You could create `Select` `MethodInfo` this way:

```
var selM = typeof(Enumerable)
         .GetMethods()
         .Where(x => x.Name == "Select" )
         .First().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity), typeof(string));
```

and your Expression you could create as:

```
var selExpression = Expression.Call(null, selM, param , lambda);
```

Important is, that first parameter of `Expression.Call` is null, `Select` is a static extension method and it don't have any instance to be called on.

`lambda` hier is a lamda expression from your property Expression

```
var prop= Expression.Property(entity, propertyName);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
```

Comment: I am stuck on the lamda. I don't know what param is. I have tried lots of stuff including this Expression.Lambda(property, (MemberExpression) innerProperty);

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!
var lambda = Expression.Lambda((MemberExpression)innerProperty, innerParam);